# WP Nav Menu: String replacements

Tags: menus

I have a short function to clean up the WP Nav Menu.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','strip_classes');

function strip_classes($a){ 
    return (in_array('menu-item-71',$a))? array('contact') : array(); 
}
```

The class name `menu-item-71` of a certain nav point is replaced by `contact`. Now I’d like a second nav point with a class named `menu-item-34` to be renamed to `about-me`. How is this possible?

Comment: _If_ this code works (I haven't tested it) then you can solve the second problem in exactly the same way you solved the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Why does this need to be done programmatically?  WordPress's menu editor lets you manually add a CSS class.  If you aren't seeing this option then look in the top, right of your screen for the "Screen Options" and click it so that it expands.  Then check "CSS Classes".

[image: Add CSS Classes from Screen Options]

[image: Now add your custom class]

Comment: Because I’d like to remove all the other (for me) useless classes and IDs that WP adds automatically like `menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page` …

Comment: Ok.  Was just throwing this out there in case you didn't know about it.  The classes might be useless but they aren't really causing any problem.  Just seems like you are creating extra work for yourself (says the queen of creating extra work for herself)

Comment: You’re probably right—it’s just because I’d like to keep the code as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

With helgatheviking’s advice in mind giving the nav items speaking class names I came across this solution, with `about-me` and `contact` being the two classes that won’t be removed.

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'my_css_attributes_filter', 100, 1);

function my_css_attributes_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('about-me', 'contact')) : '';
}
```